# Unable to find the correct syntax in a Row-Level Formula

Tags: lightning, datetime, date

Like others, new to salesforce and struggling with what is likely a simple issue, please forgive. I am working in Leaseworks, an application written on the salesforce platform. I have a column of numbers associated with a column of dates. I used the formula

```
(leaseworks__Utilization_Snapshot__c.leaseworks__TSN_as_of_Date__c - 
 leaseworks__Aircraft__c.leaseworks__Last_TSN_Utilization__c)
```

but this returns the difference between an original benchmark figure (the Last TSN Utilisation) and the updated monthly figure and so looks like this [image] What I want to do is to subtract the TSN as of Date figure from the one shown in the quarter before. i.e. in this case 39691 (from Snapshot Date 31MAR23) - 38953 (from Snapshot Date 31DEC22) = 738. Can anyone advise me on how to write this correctly? Very frustrating reading the SF help.